# Firebase functions stopped working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'

I have a project that was working. Now when I try to deploy, it fails. I have run `npm i from the functions folder. I have 'firebase-functions' in my package. I have deleted package-lock, and reinstalled. I have removed firebase-functions and firebase-admin and readded.

We are using this in production, so this is very frustrating as I pushed firebase for a simple test project.

Very confused. Thanks.

Comment: Also when I go to the Google cloud platform to look at the code that was deployed, it seems to be an older version. I can delete the function, and then reapply but an older version of my code seems to get deployed, this is very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project you should have this structure:

```
myproject
 +- .firebaserc    # Hidden file that helps you quickly switch between
 |                 # projects with `firebase use`
 |
 +- firebase.json  # Describes properties for your project
 |
 +- functions/     # Directory containing all your functions code
      |
      +- package.json  # npm package file describing your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- index.js      # main source file for your Cloud Functions code
      |
      +- node_modules/ # directory where your dependencies (declared in
                   # package.json) are installed
```

You are getting this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'

means the module `firebase-functions` is not inside `node-modules` folder. Thats probably since you moved it to another place, but it needs to be inside `node-module` in your project structure

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but yes that is my structure and yes, that folder exist within node_modules in functions. This was working. I have deployed many times, just today it failed. 

Also if I deploy something and it fails, shouldn't the previous version still work? That is a pretty bad deploy process, no?

Comment: For what it's worth, running ```firebase serve --only functions``` works fine locally.

Comment: in your `package-json` do you have firebase-functions dependencies and do you have this `"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",` inside scripts in package-json?

Comment: I have ```firebase-functions``` in my package.json within functions folder, but I do not have that script section. Is that new? Is that needed by firebase on the server side? Adding it makes no difference however. That is the code I use to deploy. oops did that wrong. trying now....

Comment: That is totally strange. YES, that worked. Running ```npm run deploy``` works but running ```firebase deploy --only functions``` does not. I guess it's a version difference with global firebase versus local? No idea. 

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: It's always just worked with firebase directly on command line and firebase init (at least the version I used) didn't add that scripts section. I will from now on. :)

Comment: it should work from the command line but you didnt have the scripts that why, maybe you didnt get the complete package.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159431/discussion-between-enric-ribas-and-peter-haddad).